# Spin during gravitational collapse

Tags: angular-momentum, astrophysics, quantum-spin, stars, stellar-physics

During or upon the ending of the gravitational collapse of a rotating star, can it be reasonably hypothesized that a collision between particles of half-integral spin might result either in a change of that spin to integral spin, or in the replacement of either or both of them by one or more particles each of integral spin?

Comment: Or any other way that two particles of half spin can interact. They can scatter off each other, they could annihilate and produce a spin 1 or a spin 0 particle, and other variations. Gravitational collapse could have an effect towards the end because they'd be in a strong gravitational field and it might have a slightly different effect on each, the tidal effect. Their rotational angular momentum could also have a differential 'tidal' like  effect. Two different spins will be affected by the spinning gravitational field, so they might be pulled together or apart, or affect their end spin

Comment: There must be a simple way to calculate how strong the grav field has to be to affect it, I don't know offhand how to simplify it from having to write down the grav effect on a spinning particle using the Kerr metric. Somebody here may

Comment: @ Bob Bee.  Thanks for the verification.  The likeliest possibility might be in the orbiting of two fermions around each other, in an epicycle that would probably be very distorted.   Perhaps this might be a valid way of describing the development of the repellent form of gravity within a black hole, which Poplawski describes as averting formation of any singularity but would nevertheless germinate a new local universe (apparently on a drastically reduced scale) within it.  I can't read his equations, but, as Higgs and inflaton particles would have spin zero, it may be what they're describing.

Comment: Sorry, not verifying anything, just pointing out that in GR there can be angular momentum interactions. With no Einstein Cartan. There's GR solutions that show a small effect dependent on the body or particle's angular momentum. And there can be spin spin interactions in their inertial frames due to nuclear and EM forces. But verifying in any way Poplawski I cannot. I have not seen since he came out with the universe inside a universe and an alternative to inflation that it has been taken seriously. Whether there is some torsion or not requires some falsifiable measurement.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and helpful advice.  Poplawski's view's falsifiable if there's absolutely no preferred direction of rotation.  Cai's 2012 "Direction dependence of the deceleration parameter"  supports a marginally preferred direction.  Bengaly's 2016 "Probing cosmological isotropy" discounts it on the basis of other supernovae studies, but strongly recommends systematic and ongoing reviews of the issue as future and more detailed data are received.  (I guess the CMB will never stop shining.)  I was concerned with analogies that might help me describe P.'s 2010 "Cosmology with torsion".